# Яндекс Карты API Указать изначальные координаты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Возник вопрос по установке изначальных координат в яндекс мапу. В js не сильно силен. Подскажите как реализовать установку изначальных параметров. А то сначало мапу в центр Москвы грузит, потом нижний Новгород.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);
    function init(){ 
        var myMap;
        myMap = new ymaps.Map("block-map", {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10
        });
        myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
        myMap.controls.add("zoomControl", {position: {top: 15, left: 15}});

        // Поиск координат центра Нижнего Новгорода.
        ymaps.geocode('Нижний Новгород', {results: 1}).then(function (res) {
                // Выбираем первый результат геокодирования.
                var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
                    // Координаты геообъекта.
                    coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
                    // Область видимости геообъекта.
                    bounds = firstGeoObject.properties.get('boundedBy');
                firstGeoObject.options.set('preset', 'islands#darkBlueDotIconWithCaption');
                // Получаем строку с адресом и выводим в иконке геообъекта.
                firstGeoObject.properties.set('iconCaption', firstGeoObject.getAddressLine());

                // Добавляем первый найденный геообъект на карту.
                myMap.geoObjects.add(firstGeoObject);
                // Масштабируем карту на область видимости геообъекта.
                myMap.setBounds(bounds, {checkZoomRange: true});
                /**
                 * Если нужно добавить по найденным геокодером координатам метку со своими стилями и контентом балуна, создаем новую метку по координатам найденной и добавляем ее на карту вместо найденной.
                 */
                /**
                 var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
                 iconContent: 'моя метка',
                 balloonContent: 'Содержимое балуна <strong>моей метки</strong>'
                 }, {
                 preset: 'islands#violetStretchyIcon'
                 });

                 myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
                 */
            });

//                                var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.7649, 37.63836] , {},
//                                    { iconLayout: 'default#image',
//                                      iconImageHref: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/map_marker.png',
//                                      iconImageSize: [50, 50],
//                                      iconImageOffset: [-20, -47] });     
//
//                                myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Строчка center: [55.76, 37.64] задает изначальные координаты. Строчка myMap.setBounds(bounds, {checkZoomRange: true}); задает координаты после геокодирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для отображения центра карты при инициализации нужно верно указать параметр center. В вашем коде достаточно инициализировать карту после вычисления координат города и подставить значение coords в параметр center:

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init(){ 

    ymaps.geocode('Нижний Новгород', {results: 1}).then(function (res) {
            var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
                coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
                bounds = firstGeoObject.properties.get('boundedBy');
            firstGeoObject.options.set('preset', 'islands#darkBlueDotIconWithCaption');
            firstGeoObject.properties.set('iconCaption', firstGeoObject.getAddressLine());

    var myMap;
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("block-map", {
        center: coords,
        zoom: 10
    });
    myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
    myMap.controls.add("zoomControl", {position: {top: 15, left: 15}});
            myMap.geoObjects.add(firstGeoObject);
            myMap.setBounds(bounds, {checkZoomRange: true});
            });
}
```

Подробнее про инициализацию карт можно прочесть здесь: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/

Обратите внимание, что в таком случае при каждом создании карты будет происходить геокодирование. В API установлен суточный лимит на использование сервисов геокодирования, маршрутизации и панорам Яндекса. Для бесплатной версии API лимит составляет 25 000 запросов в сутки. https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage/